# Codebehind Does Not Publish

Tags: asp.net

I have inherited some ASP.NET web code which I have made changes to. It debugs fine. I built and published it via FTP.

The changes to the page seem fine but any changes that were made to the codebehind (e.g. different items in a dropdown list) have not been updated even though they are included and have a new datestamp on the FTP server.

Does anyone know why this would be? Is it a caching issue? Have I done something wrong when publishing?

Comment: Delete all relevant binaries and aspx / related files from the server and deploy them again.

Comment: Is it possible to restart the server instance?

Comment: @m.edmondson = Thanks for the suggestion. Their server is shared hosting so it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload a compiled application, please double checked whether you have uploaded the relevant .dll file.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. For some reason the DLL was excluded from the project. I have included it, republished and all is now well.

Answer (score 1):

When deploying, you do not need to copy any code behind files (.vb or .cs files, not sure what language you are using). You do need to make sure that you have built the solution and that you copy the contents on the bin folder out to the website.

Answer (score 1):

- Double check that the files you are copying are from the folder location to which you are publishing
- Remove the files from the server first, then copy up your newly compiled dll's

Also please post your publish options (a screenshot would be great).